# How do I write a function to add 7 and substract 2 if it is not already 0

Tags: javascript

This is what I need to do:
The snail climbs up 7 feet each day and slips back 2 feet each night.
How many days will it take the snail to get out of a well with the given depth?

Sample Input:
31

Sample Output:
6

Explanation: Let's break down the distance the snail covers each day:

```
Day 1: 7-2=5
Day 2: 5+7-2=10
Day 3: 10+7-2=15
Day 4: 15+7-2=20
Day 5: 20+7-2=25
Day 6: 25+7=32
```

So, on Day 6 the snail will reach 32 feet and get out of the well at day, without slipping back that night.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
    
}
```

Please help me, I'm like really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simple question,

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
   
    i = 0;
   
    for (; depth > 0;) {
        i++;
       
        depth -= 7
        if (depth > 0) {
            depth += 2
        }
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

What this code basically does is:

It sets a i variable which is 0, than when the depth is bigger than 0, 1 is post incremented by 1 -which means 1 is added to it- this will count the days it will take. But we must consider the nights as well, as it says, it will not fall down the night if it climbs it all in the day. Thus, we put another + 2 if the -7 doesn't make it 0.

You can read about for loops here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

I have noticed you're new to stack overflow, so please for the next time you ask, do some coding and research on your own. You mentioned you coded some bits but you just stated a function which is just same as writing nothing and asking for an answer -stack overflow is not your homework solving site!-

Answer (score 0):

In a day and a night, a snail gains a total of 5 feet. The catch here is that this gain is made up of gaining 7 feet, and then slipping back 2. Another way to think about it is that the goal is 2 less than the actual goal, but advances 7-2=5 feet per day.

To formulate this to Javascript, you need to subtract 2 from the distance, divide it by 5, and ceil the result to get the number of days as an integer:

```js
function numDays(distance) {
    return Math.ceil((distance - 2) / 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function main(distance) {
    var depth = parseInt(distance);
    //your code goes here
    var day = 0;
    var total = 0;
    while(total<depth){
        day = day + 1;
        total = total + 7;
        if(total >= depth){
            console.log(day);
            break;
        }
        total = total - 2;
    }
}
main(32)
main(51)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question pretty simple but tricky ;

The depth is already defined which is  " var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);"
So you don't have to worry declaring depth again depth.
So we need to declare variable for day and total distance at start which is
var day = 0 ; and var total =  0 ; .So here the solution :

function main() {
var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);  //defining depth

```
//your code goes here
var day = 0; //defining day
var total = 0; // distance which is at zero
while(total<depth){
    day += 1;
    total += 7;  // if the total distance is less than depth of the well the day is added by one and distance is added by 7
    if(total >= depth){
        break;   // but if the total is equal to or greater than depth the loop will break  
    }
    total -= 2; // 2 is deducted from  every step in loop except when the loop is about to ends(where the loop breaks when total=depth).
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function main() {
    var depth = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    //your code goes here
    var result = depth / 5;
    console.log(Math.round(result));
}
```